# sum content of multiple select request in a view mysql

Tags: mysql, select, view, request

I want to create view from two different select request

```
Table : Dog(name,name2)
Table : cat(name)
```

the two select are :

```
select (contactws(" ",name,name2) from Dog
select (name from Cat)
```

the view that I want must contains the sum of the two request.

Comment: Can you give an exemple of what output you want

Answer (score 0):

```
create view your_view as     
  select contactws(" ",`name`,name2) as `name` from Dog 
  union
  select `name` from Cat
```

Make sure your column names are identical if you use `union`. If they are not then alias them.